# Can't set value of JQuery UI Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 3 Sliders in one JQuery Dialog, i want them to have a maximum value, but the maximum is not only for one slider it is for the sum of all of them. My script runs fine in google chrome debuger the only problem is that the value of the slider is not updated in `$(this).slider("value", (sliderMax - sum));`

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    id = id.replace("Slider", "Value");
    var sliderMax = 27;
    $(this).slider({
        range : "min",
        min : 0,
        max : sliderMax,
        value : $("#" + id).attr("value"),
        slide : function(event, ui) {
            var sum = 0;
            $(".sliderValue").each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("id") != id) {
                    sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
                }
            });
            if ((sum + $(this).slider("value")) > sliderMax){
                $(this).slider("value", (sliderMax - sum));
            }
            $("#" + id).val(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finaly i found the solution:

```
if ((sum + ui.value) > sliderMax){
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of params of `parseInt` and `value:...` `parseInt` returns fake value when the string provided as parameter doesn't contain a number! please define the value variable outside the options as follows

```
   $(".slider").each(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
id = id.replace("Slider", "Value");
var sliderMax = 27;
var _value=$("#" + id).attr("value");
$(this).slider({
    range : "min",
    min : 0,
    max : sliderMax,
    value :value,
    slide : function(event, ui) {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".sliderValue").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("id") != id) {
                var valueString=$(this).attr("value");
                sum += parseInt(valueString);
            }
        });
        if ((sum + $(this).slider("value")) > sliderMax){
            $(this).slider("value", (sliderMax - sum));
        }
        $("#" + id).val(ui.value);
    }
  });
});
```

**EDITS**:
copied your solution to help readers

```
         if ((sum + ui.value) > sliderMax){
           return false;
         }
```

Comment: I set the value by php so it has to be a number. Also everything workes just fine in the chrome debuger i can see that all is executed perfectly only the line $(this).slider("value", (sliderMax - sum)); has no effect.

Comment: I not tryed something like this:

     if ((sum + $(this).slider("value")) > (sliderMax - 1)){
      ui.value = (sliderMax - sum);
      $(this).slide("value", ((sliderMax - sum) - 1));
     }

wich works but after the slider reaches his limit he is stuck.

Comment: Ok @HansPetersburg I suggest you add your html part in your question (if possible) so we can understand the scenario

Comment: I found the solution but thank you very much for awser me. I just searched for the wrong words in google.